# What's an easy way to make staging SVN repository

Tags: svn

I'd like emulate "private checkins" by having a separate SVN repository on my local machine just for myself. The idea is I might want the features of version control like diff, rollback, commit, but I'm not ready to have the changeset be available for the entire team. The two main reasons are, one broken builds. I might want to mark progress in between functional/sharable code. Two, large changeset on a slow connection.

I see this being a core concept of TFS but I have no control over which VCS we use. Even more flexible are the DVSC type products like git and Hg, but again I can't change the system nor do we really need the advanced flexibility of a full distributed version control system.

The two issues I want to tackle to keep this simple are:

1) **Repo-to-repo commit.** I need an easy way to commit the changes to the team's repository if I'm now commiting to this different one.

2) **Update correctness.** If I'm updating my copy to have all the changesets from the rest of the team, I need this to still work pulling changes back to my privaterepo's working copy.

Has anyone done this? Most similar questions are answered with avocation of git. I believe this is overkill for my situation. I can have my local repo be whatever I want, but I have no control over the server for the team.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to branch your changes on the main Subversion.

When you're done, merge the branch back into the main trunk.

Comment: ... and don't forget in process merge trunk into your branch, if you don't want crying and screaming in horror later, on reinegrate

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read http://hginit.com/ -- it tells a story about SVN user who discovered hg, and how he learned (the hard way), and what he could do with what he learned.

In your case, I'd recommend to create your own personal `hg` repository on your own machine, make local branches and commits, keep the whole development process inside, and commit to the team server only when ready.

hginit explains how to setup the "intermediate" repository between you and your team repository, and there's no reason why one of them may not be SVN, if they need it.

Comment: a) 0 part of hginit of Joel Spolsky is "a cry of Subversion lamer", sorry! So - **read carefully** b) He wrote nothing about hgsubversion, but "Tempora mutantur..." c) Joel wrote **nothing** about work with **Mercurial and Subversion in parralllel** - his manta "Drop Subversion"